# Smoothing Lemma

Tags: integration, derivatives, differential-topology

Given a $C^0$ function $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ that is smooth everywhere except at $c$ (where $a<c<b$), and has positive derivative everywhere except at $c$, the claim is that there exists a function $G:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ that is smooth and has positive derivative everywhere (including $c$), and that agrees with $g$ in some neighborhood about $a$ and some neighborhood about $b$.

According to Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology*, one such function that fits the bill is $G(x) = g(a) + \int_{a}^{x}[k\rho(s)+g'(s)(1-\rho(s))]ds$, where $\rho$ is a smooth nonnegative function on $[a,b]$ that vanishes outside of $[u,v]$ (where $a<u<c<v<b$), is equal to $1$ on some neighborhood about $c$, and satisfies $\int_{a}^{b}\rho(s) ds = 1$. $k$ is the constant defined $k=g(b)-g(a)-\int_{a}^{b}g'(s)(1-\rho(s))ds$.

I have been able to show that $G$ as defined above agrees with $g$ on the required neighborhoods, and that $k>0$; however, I have been completely unable to prove that $G$ has positive derivative everywhere. Its derivative is certainly positive in the neighborhood about $c$, and near $a$ and $b$, but I don't see how one can prove that it is positive everywhere. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the answer. So I give a hint here.

> **Hint** $$0\leq\rho\leq1 \text{ ,} \forall x\in[a,b]$$

---

Actually you are right. The hint is not depended on the condition $\int_a^b\rho dx=1$. And we should construct a $\rho$ satisfying the hint at first.

> **Lemma**
>   If $M$ is a smooth manifold, and $F\subset G\subset M$, $F$ is closed and $G$ is open. Then we have a $\rho$ satistying 
>   $$F\subset \{p\in M|\rho(p)=1\}\subset\text{supp}\rho\subset G$$
>   and $0\leq\rho\leq1$.

This **Lemma** can be found in *Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

Then choose $M=(a,b)$ and $F=[u,v]$, $G=(a,b)$. Then $\rho$ will satisfies the hint.

Comment: Since $G'(x)=k \rho(x)+g'(x)(1-\rho(x))$, it follows that if $\rho$ meets the condition you described, then the result follows. However, if $b-a<1$, then $0 \leq\rho \leq1 \Rightarrow \int_{a}^{b}\rho(s)ds<1$, which is not allowed (it *is* possible, though, if $b-a>1$). Can we simply multiply $[a,b]$ by some constant $K$ (so that $Kb-Ka>1$, let $h:[Ka,Kb] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined $h(x)=g(\frac{x}{K})$, get the desired function $H:[Ka,Kb] \to \mathbb{R}$ which meets the requisite conditions, and let $G=H(Kx)$?